# How to include completion handlers for multiple functions in swift?

Tags: swift, function, synchronization, completionhandler

Consider this code:

```
func test() {
    A()
    B()
    C()
    D()
    E()
}
```

Each function here have their own set of actions like calling API's, parsing them, writing results in file, uploading to servers, etc etc.

I want to run this functions *one by one*. I read about completion handlers. My problem with completion handlers are:

- All examples given to understand completion handlers was having just two methods
- I don't want to place this functions in some other function. I want all function calls (A to E) inside `Test()` function alone

Can someone help on this?

Comment: *I want to run this functions one by one.* Why do you think it is not the case? Note: completion handlers are "code" that are executed at the end of something (generally some asynchronous operation)

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to do, you just need to add a closure argument to call on completion. For example:

```
func a(completion: (() -> Void)) {
    // When all async operations are complete:
    completion()
}

func b(completion: (() -> Void)) {
    // When all async operations are complete:
    completion()
}

func c(completion: (() -> Void)) {
    // When all async operations are complete:
    completion()
}

func d(completion: (() -> Void)) {
    // When all async operations are complete:
    completion()
}

func e(completion: (() -> Void)) {
    // When all async operations are complete:
    completion()
}

func test() {
    a {
        b {
            c {
                d {
                    e {
                        // All have now completed.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this looks horrible. One problem with multiple async operations, non concurrently is that you end up with this horrible nesting.

Solutions to this do exist, I personally recommend [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit). It encapsulates blocks in easy chaining methods, which is far cleaner.

Comment: I think, we should add this line in each method's(A-E) end:
completion()

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at reactive programming and observable chains. [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) will be an excellent library for you. Reactive programming is very popular right now and was created exactly to solve problems like yours. It enables you to easily create a process (like an assembly line) that transforms inputs into your desired outputs. For example, your code in Rx would look like:

```
A()
 .flatMap { resultsFromA in
    B(resultsFromA)
 }
 .flatMap { resultsFromB in
    C(resultsFromB)
 }
 .flatMap { resultsFromC in
    D(resultsFromC)
 }
 .flatMap { resultsFromD in
    E(resultsFromD)
 }
 .subscribe(onNext: { finalResult in

  //result from the process E, subscribe starts the whole 'assembly line'
  //without subscribing nothing will happen, so you can easily create observable chains and reuse them throughout your app

 })
```

This code sample would create a process where you'd transform results from your initial API call (A), into parsed results (B), then write parsed results to a file (C) etc. Those processes can be synchronous or asynchronous. Reactive programming can be understood as Observable pattern on steroids.

Comment: Rx is a good way to go, however it is a steep learning curve and requires an entire paradigm shift. If you're in a position to do that then by all means its a great idea. Unfortunately, I wasn't, and hence found PromiseKit to be a nice compromise.

Comment: I agree with Jacob King, it requires a paradigm shift and some time to adjust. However, the payoff is really good and in the end you learn a valuable thing that will boost your productivity for a long time.

Comment: Exactly as FruitAdict says, you will reap the rewards in the long term if you're in a position to make the shift.